# MPI_Scatter & MPI_Bcast solution in one application. How do I get the partition print the partition size

Tags: c++, mpi

Im new to MPI, this application involves implementation of MPI_Bcast and MPI_Scatter. The requirement is first the root should broadcast to the nodes the size of the partition using MPI_Bcast and then scatter the section of each array to a node. My root is working ok but the nodes are not receiving the values of the array hence the calculation of the average is skewed. here  below is the code that I have so far

```
/** includes **/
   #include <iostream>
   #include <mpi.h>


    // function that will implement the coordinator job of this application
    void coordinator(int world_size) {

    std::cout << " coordinator rank [0] starting " << std::endl;

    // generate 100000 random integers and store them in an array

    int values[40];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 40; i++){
        values[i] = rand() % 10;
        std::cout << values[i] << ", ";
        if (i % 10 == 9) std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    // determine the size of each partition by dividing 100000 by the world size
    // it is impertative that the world_size divides this evenly

    int partition_size = 40 / world_size;
    std::cout << " coordinator rank [0] partition size is " << partition_size  << "\n" << std::endl;

    // broadcast the partition size to each node so they can setup up memory as appropriate

    MPI_Bcast(&partition_size, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    std::cout << " coordinator rank [0] broadcasted partition size\n" << std::endl;

    // generate an average for our partition

    int total = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (40 / world_size); i++)
        total += values[i];
    float average = (float)total / (40 / world_size);
    std::cout << " coordinator rank [0] average is " << average << "\n" << std::endl;

    // call a reduce operation to get the total average and then divide that by the world size

    float total_average = 0;
    MPI_Reduce(&average, &total_average, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    std::cout << " total average is " << total_average / world_size << std::endl;
}
// function that will implement the participant job of this applicaiton

void participant(int world_rank, int world_size) {

    std::cout << " participant rank [" << world_rank << "] starting" << std::endl;

    // get the partition size from the root and allocate memory as necessary

    int partition_size = 0;
    MPI_Bcast(&partition_size, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    std::cout << " participant rank [" << world_rank << "] recieved partition size of " <<
        partition_size << std::endl;

    // allocate the memory for our partition

    int *partition = new int[partition_size];

    // generate an average for our partition

    int total = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < partition_size; i++)
        total += partition[i];
    float average = (float)total / partition_size;
    std::cout << " participant rank [" << world_rank << "] average is " << average << std::endl;

    // call a reduce operation to get the total average and then divide that by the world size

    float total_average = 0;
    MPI_Reduce(&average, &total_average, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // as we are finished with the memory we should free it

    delete partition;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // initialise the MPI library

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);


    // determine the world size
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    // determine our rank in the world

    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    // print out the rank and size

    std::cout << " rank [" << world_rank << "] size [" << world_size << "]" << std::endl;

    // if we have a rank of zero then we are the coordinator. if not we are a participant
    // in the task

    if (world_rank == 0){
        coordinator(world_size);
    } 
    else{
        participant(world_rank, world_size);
    }

    int *values = new int[40];
    int *partition_size = new int[40 / world_size];

    // run the scatter operation and then display the contents of all 4 nodes

    MPI_Scatter(values, 40 / world_size, MPI_INT, partition_size, 40 / world_size,
        MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    std::cout << "rank " << world_rank << " partition: ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 40 / world_size; i++)
        std::cout << partition_size[i] << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // finalise the MPI library
    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

Here is what I get after running the code

I need to be getting this

1, 7, 4, 0, 9, 4, 8, 8, 2, 4,

5, 5, 1, 7, 1, 1, 5, 2, 7, 6,

1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 6, 8, 5,

7, 6, 1, 8, 9, 2, 7, 9, 5, 4,

but I'm getting this

rank 0 partition: -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451,     -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451,

rank 3 partition: -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451,

rank 2 partition: -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451,

rank 1 partition: -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451, -842150451,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are scattering an array of **uninitialised** data:

```
int *values = new int[40];
int *partition_size = new int[40 / world_size];

// values is never initialised

MPI_Scatter(values, 40 / world_size, MPI_INT, partition_size, 40 / world_size,
    MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

`-842150451` is `0xCDCDCDCD`, with which value Microsoft CRT fills newly allocated memory in debug mode (in release mode the memory content will be left as is after the allocation).

You have to put the calls to `MPI_Scatter` inside the corresponding coordinator/participant function.

Comment: I initialised in the coordinator method but now my average is still wrong